# Magento Dynamic Content based on Store Mode

Tags: magento

In the wireframe I'm working from I have three divs on the home page. The content of these divs needs to change based on the store mode. For example USA version of the site will 
display different content in each div than the Euro version. i.e

---

USA Site

Welcome to bobs widgets

[ usa content 1 ] [ usa content 2] [ usa content 3 ]

---

Euro Site

Welcome to bobs widgets

[ euro content 1 ] [ euro content 2] [ euro content 3 ]

---

From what I understand of static blocks these point to single content entry. So having home_content_1, home_content_2 etc won't work so well, if what is inside that needs to change based on the site mode.

What I want to do is something like. " Get all 'home page feature' content for this country / store, display each in a div "

( P.S I'm a Magento Noob, but not a noob developer, despite the non technical nature of this question :) )

Answer (score 0):

When creating static block you can attach them to a store view.

Create one block home_content_1_storecode for each store.

Then you just have to call the block adding the storecode in php and it will call the right block depending on the store you're on.

If you don't use the same design template for each store, you can also use phtml to show your blocks. Each store will have its own block.